# Query to GraphDB's repository with custom functions SPARQL using Jena

Tags: java, dataset, sparql, jena, graphdb

I've implemented some custom functions SPARQL with Jena ARQ following the [Property Function docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/writing_propfuncs.html). Those functions work with a local dataset using a model:

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

model.read(new FileInputStream("data/data.ttl"), null, "TTL");

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString) ; // the queryString contains a custom property function defined with Jena

try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
           ...
          }
```

However, I need to apply these property functions for queries on a dataset on my Graphdb Repository, so I tried to connect program to GraphDB using Jena.

I've tried following [Using GraphDB with Jena](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/using-graphdb-with-jena.html) but it seems out of date and cannot be implemented because SailRepository.initialize(); was deprecated and SesameDataset doesn't longer exist to initialize my model.

```
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryConnection;
import com.ontotext.jena.SesameDataset;

...
RepositoryConnection connection = repository.getConnection();

// finally, create the DatasetGraph instance
SesameDataset dataset = new SesameDataset(connection);
```

I've also tried RDFConnection of Jena but it doesn't work with my custom functions since there's no model backend to apply queries.

Can anyone tell me where can I find the SesameDataset to import or whether there is other way to query a GraphDB's repository with custom functions?

Comment: Your custom SPARQL functions implemnted in Jena indeed can't work on GraphDB since GraphDB would have to know of those functions because the query string is simply sent to GraphDB which evaluates the query and returns the resultset in a standard SPARQL response format. Two options: a) use RDF4J which also means you have to reimplement your stuff and put the JAr on the GraphDB classpath or b) use Javascript functions: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/javascript-functions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I was looking hopelessly for a solution with Jena to do not have to reimplement all my custom functions but it seems I have to it anyway. I'll try out following your suggestion. Have a nice day!

Comment: This isn't about the communication - which is the standard SPARQL protocol. The question mentions "property functions" which stay within the SPARQL syntax but are part of triple pattern matching and provide the ability to set variables and provide multiple matches.

Comment: @AndyS I'm not sure understanding your comment, could you clarify it? I'm looking for a way to use my property functions written with Jena to query on GraphDB.

Comment: Custom function for filters and custom property functions are different things. Jeen is talking about filter functions.  
In both cases, the custom code is executed inside the query engine and code will be engine specific.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably make your life a lot easier by using RDF4J to communicate with GraphDB, instead of Jena - it is the [recommended Java API for this purpose](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/devhub/programming.html) by the GraphDB developers.

You can implement custom SPARQL functions in RDF4J/GraphDB by following [this tutorial](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/tutorials/custom-sparql-functions/) - in summary it's a matter of implementing the `org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.function.Function` interface and making sure your implementation is on the classpath of GraphDB and registered as an SPI implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I was looking hopelessly for a solution with Jena to do not have to reimplement all my custom functions but it seems I have to do it anyway. I'll try out following your suggestion. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Jeen (the creator of rdf4j) pointed how you can create custom functions.

However, as AndyS (the creator of Jena) points out, you seem to need magic predicates (custom property functions). For that I think that you need to create a plugin and implement pattern interpretation as described here: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/plug-in-api.html#pattern-interpretation.

Most plugins are open source at https://github.com/Ontotext-AD, so you can see many examples. I know for sure that https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-geosparql-plugin uses magic predicates, eg

- `?x geo:sfWithin ?y` is a predicate that checks (or returns) all features where `?x` is within `?y`
- `geof:sfWithin(?x,?y)` (note the different namespace) is a function that checks the same condition, but must be called with bound params: it cannot find features satisfying the condition.

See [this search](https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-geosparql-plugin/search?q=sfWithin) and then see [IRI GEO_SF_WITHIN](https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-geosparql-plugin/blob/5d5e8d1b6de3172714b9a1e57e6eb6459183923d/src/main/java/com/useekm/indexing/GeoConstants.java#L43), search with [GEO_SF_WITHIN](https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-geosparql-plugin/search?q=GEO_SF_WITHIN), and you find com/ontotext/trree/geosparql/GeoSparqlFunction.java and com/useekm/geosparql/algebra/PropertyToFunctionOptimizer.java

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I'm having a look at the plugin. Have a nice day!